# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Function.all (<anonymous>) Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I set up a cloud function in this way:

```
exports.changeIsVisibleFieldAfterDay = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
  return db.collectionGroup("Moments")
      .where("isVisible", "==", true)
      .where("timestamp", "<=", d)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          Promise.all().doc.ref.update({isVisible: false}, {merge: true});
        });
        return null;
      });
});
```

When I insert `Promise.all()` to update all documents in sub-collections I receive this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at Function.all (<anonymous>)
```

When I don't use `Promise.all()` the documents are updated correctly but I know what If I want to update a huge number of documents I need a `Promise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the Mozilla JS [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) the `promise.All` function expects an array of promises as it's input, since you're not providing one the error warns you that undefined (i.e. no argument) is not iterable.

Actually what you want is something like the code below (already tested):

```js
db.collectionGroup("Moments")
    .where("isVisible", "==", true)
    .where("timestamp", "<=", d)
    .get()
    .then((querySnap) => {
        // Create an array of the promises returned by update()
        let promises = [];
        querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
            promises.push(doc.ref.update({hello:"yes"}, {merge: true}))
        });
        // Resolve the promises
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then((x) => console.log("Docs updated"))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });
```

Comment: the reasoning make sense and it works, thank you!